# SliceVectorPlot3D example code gives empty plot

Tags: plotting, visualization

I want to use `SliceVectorPlot3D` for visualization, but it always returns an empty plot. I have been trying to run several of the examples from the documentation, like

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

but none of them work for me. I am running Mathematica 12.2.0 on Arch Linux. It does not work on a Windows virtual machine either. I have confirmed it to be working on my Windows desktop, however. I noticed that `ListSliceVectorPlot3D` does not work for me either, but `SliceDensityPlot3D` does, for some reason.

I have not found out about any issues with `SliceVectorPlot3D` online.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: "different versions of Mathematica" - but which version numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @J.M. I edited my post and added the version numbers.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in V12.1.1 running on MacOS.

Comment: Works ok on ver 12.0.0.0 in Windows.  Also, try either saving and restarting the notebook or clearing all variables using Clear["Global`*"] then running the code again.

Comment: Interesting that you guys cannot reproduce the problem. I have restarted and saved the notebook, cleared all variables, restarted mathematica itself, but no success. Also, I have noticed that my `x`, `y` and `z` variables get assigned when I run the example command I provided. I cannot seem to clear them then afterwards without invoking `Quit[]`.

Comment: Correction: I can apparently run it on my windows machine, just not on my linux machine and not either on my windows virtual machine. I have edited my post to for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the following method.

```
Style[SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, 
  "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}], 
 RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}]
```

```
Style[SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, 
  "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}], 
 RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

If one of above work,you can go to the setting of Mathematica by

Format -> Option Inspector -> Selection -> Global Preferences -> Lookup

and search `3DRenderingEngine` then select `Mesa`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Both of those make me able to render the graph as expected.