# Plot3D returns empty plot, even the examples from the documentation

Tags: plotting

Edit: Solution as in [SliceVectorPlot3D example code gives empty plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240037/slicevectorplot3d-example-code-gives-empty-plot/240097#240097) thanks to @cvgmt for pointing it out

Plot3D always returns an empty box. This even happens for the examples in the documentation, e.g.

[image]

Any ideas?

Version: "13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" I am running it on a virtual Mint installation

Comment: I can't replicate this. It works fine. I am using v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Include your OS detail and run `$Version` to include Mathematica version to your post. Thanks.

Comment: Set  "3DRenderingEngine" to  "Mesa" (Format -> Option Inspector  and search "3DRenderingEngine".  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240097/72111

Comment: @cvgmt It does not seem to help, though every time I reopen the option inspector it has reverted to "Automatic" (yes I did click apply) edit: it did actually work it just took a few attempts

Comment: @user14763624 can you try with a fresh kernel and let us know? I, also, was unable to replicate the issue